# SpannableStringBuilder font color

Tags: android

Ok I am sorry for the horrible title, I did not know how else to put it. I was using spannablestringbuilder to do custom font coloring.

Here is the first code snippet

```
 protected void onStop() {
        try{
            clientskt.close();
        }catch(final Exception ii){


            Server.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    SpannableStringBuilder errorsocketclose = new SpannableStringBuilder("[ERROR] "+ii+" [ERROR]\n");

                    errorsocketclose.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#B00000")), 0,errorsocketclose.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    errorsocketclose.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#000000")),8, ii.toString().length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    editText.append(errorsocketclose);
                }
            });
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

and it would be the last error and nine spaces before it would be in red.

in use) [ERROR]

Now if I put this in

```
int letshopto = ii.toString().length() + 9;
```

just [ERROR] would be red as expected.

I had same problem with different set and I had to + 9 to the length to fix it.

also as writing this I realized I can remove the int and just put + 9 in the line. like this.

```
ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#000000")),8,ii.toString().length() + 9, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Anyone know how I can make it different where I don't have to put + 9, because I thought .length() would've done it.

Comment: Not only your title is horrible,  the body too, i don't understand what you mean a all...

Comment: Yeah no doubt there, I wrote this up at 3 am and put it in code review and went to bed, and just copy and paste over here, without proofreading.

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
String error = "[ERROR]";
int start = error.length() + ii.toString().length();
int end = start + error.length();
```

this is in the case i understood that all you wanted to do is color the error string